# Write a procedure to display information of those students whose total is in between specified range?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Table: stud_master

```
create table stud_master
(
  stud_no number(5) primary key,
  name varchar(10),
  dob date
);
```

Table: stud_marksheet

```
create table stud_marksheet
(
stud_no number(5) references stud_master,
sub1 number(3) check(sub1>=1 and sub1<=100,
sub2 number(3) check(sub2>=1 and sub2<=100,
sub3 number(3) check(sub3>=1 and sub3<=100,
total number(5),
percentage number (5,2),
result varchar(5) check(result in('Pass','Fail'))
);
```

These both are my tables

I had tried to make a procedure, but I don't know how to do it.

```
create or replace procedure prorange
    (min in out number, max in out number) is
begin
    min:=&min;
    max:=&max;

    select * from stud_master s full join stud_marksheet m on s.stud_no=m.stud_no and s.total:=min and s.total:=max;

    for i in min..max
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('stud_no:'||' '||i.stud_no);
        dbms_output.put_line('name:'||' '||i.name);
        dbms_output.put_line('sub1:'||' '||i.sub1);
        dbms_output.put_line('sub2:'||' '||i.sub2);
        dbms_output.put_line('sub3:'||' '||i.sub3);
        dbms_output.put_line('total:'||' '||i.total);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Have a look at [Cursor FOR loops](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm). Also get rid of `min:=&min;` etc. `min` and `max` are already the names of SQL functions so maybe choose different names, and make them `in` only.

Comment: I don't know how to do cursor nd procedure differently. If i made procedure. ..which logic should i put in procedure?

Comment: It’s explained with examples in the link in my comment above.

Comment: Oh ok sir.. i will see that and then try nd then msg u

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
create or replace procedure prorange
  (min in out number, max in out number) 
is
begin
  FOR i IN (select s.stud_no
                 , s.name
                 , m.sub1
                 , m.sub2
                 , m.sub3
                 , m.total 
              from stud_master s 
              full join stud_marksheet m 
                     on s.stud_no=m.stud_no
             where m.total between min and max)
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('stud_no:'||' '||i.stud_no);
    dbms_output.put_line('name:'||' '||i.name);
    dbms_output.put_line('sub1:'||' '||i.sub1);
    dbms_output.put_line('sub2:'||' '||i.sub2);
    dbms_output.put_line('sub3:'||' '||i.sub3);
    dbms_output.put_line('total:'||' '||i.total);
  end loop;
end;
```

There are also some code smells in your code:

- Make the parameters only In-parameters and not in/out-parameter, since you are not modifying the values. This also enables the call with constant values (e.g. prorange(1,5))
- Use left join instead of full join, as there is allways a master record in stud_master per reference left join is sufficient and faster then the used full join.

Comment: Sir my stud_no is coming as error... Showing component stud_no must be declared

Comment: The database doesn't know, whether to take the column from table stud_master or stud_marksheet as it accurs in both tables. You should query the desired columns explicitly (not select *) to tell the database whicht data you want to query exactly.